# Regex remove repeated +-*/ characters from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I do calculator, and this string appear at my view side of app.
I need a reg expression to remove repeated `+` `-` `*` `/` characters from a string.

**Examples**

| How to get this | From this |
| --- | --- |
| `111+22-33*4` | `111+++22-33*****4` |
| `22243+11` | `22243++++11` |

“565656565656565656565”

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not a free consulting service.  And note that a regular expression is not necessarily the best way to solve this.  A simple loop would be easier to understand.

Comment: `'111+++22-33*****4'.replace(/(?<op>[\+\-\*\/])\k<op>+/g, '$1')`

Comment: @AndyRay That looks nice enough for an answer.

Comment: @KateSuv Please check if my edit of your question is ok. What about this “565656565656565656565”?

Comment: `+-` should be replaced with what? or kept intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log('+-111+++22-33*****4//////3'.replace(/([-/*+])\1+/g, '$1'));
```

Analysis:

`([-/*+])` - capture your target character to replace into a capture group
`\1+` - match any number of repeating captured character
`/g` - global replace
`$1` - replace with 1 captured character

An `Array::reduce()` one-liner:

```js
const str = '+-111+++22-33*****4//////3';

const res = str.split('').reduce((r,c,i,arr) => i && arr[i-1] === c && '*/+-'.includes(c) ? r : r + c, '');

console.log(res);
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000">

const str = '+-111+++22-33*****4//////3';

// @benchmark Tim
function strip(s) {
    var out = "";
    var last = 'X';
    for( let i = 0; i < s.length; i++ )
    {
        const c = s[i];
        if( "+-*/".indexOf(c) < 0 || c != last )
        {
            out = out + c;
        }
        last = c;
    }
    return out;
}
//@run
strip(str)

// @benchmark regexp
str.replace(/([-/*+])\1+/g, '$1');

// @benchmark Array::reduce()
str.split('').reduce((r,c,i,arr) => i && arr[i-1] === c && '*/+-'.includes(c) ? r : r + c, '');

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like [`str.replace(/[\/*+-]+\B/g, '')`](https://tio.run/##JcoxCoAgGEDhvVO4af2pmA1BtHSNahCRKCRFpeub1Rve9J3qVlGHwyd6Dzlbk1BMAU0IAxVCAEDXUSmbt55/STxW1Y/KWTDeKm0IX1beAN1gnfneIozrwrS7orOGWbeTgusx5wc) would even perform a bit better, but this is not so accurate. Nice benchmark! :)

Comment: @bobblebubble a nice regexp, it's faster, but the problem is the OP is silent. it's not clear how `-+` should be replaced and if there're any other validations to restrict source strings...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this with a simple loop.

```js
function strip(s) {
    var out = "";
    var last = 'X';
    for( let i = 0; i < s.length; i++ )
    {
        const c = s[i];
        if( "+-*/".indexOf(c) < 0 || c != last )
        {
            out = out + c;
        }
        last = c;
    }
    return out;
}

console.log( strip("2222++++444"));
console.log( strip("111+++222***333///444+-5"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function simplifyExpression(expression) {
  return expression.replace(/[+*\/-]+/g, match => match.charAt(0));
}

const inputExpression = "111+++22-33*****4";
const simplifiedExpression = simplifyExpression(inputExpression);
console.log(simplifiedExpression);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).